# UserInteraction enable for subview only

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, subview

I have a view and view.UserInteractionenabled = no and a button is added to the view. i need to click the button only . is it possible to enable interaction for button only.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A view cannot receive touches unless `userInteractionEnabled` is `YES` for the view and all of  its superviews up to the `UIWindow` object.

You can make a subclass of `UIView` to contain the button, and make it ignore touches outside the button by overriding `hitTest:withEvent:`.  Example:

```
@interface MyView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

@end


@implementation MyView

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView *subview = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    return subview == self.button ? subview : nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: This will not help if there is a button in the superview, which is right under the button in its subview(like any menu that opened above some superview) than if you hit the one in the subview and detect only him, it still will fire the button in the superview.